# Can someone please explain the second term of the expression for mass flow across the fluid element?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, computational-physics

[image]

I've recently started studying from the text "An Introduction to Computational Fluid Dynamics" by Versteeg and Malalasekera. I'm currently on the topic of derivation of the fundamental governing equations in chapter two. I've taken two fluid mechanics courses before but have not encountered the second term in the mass flow rate expression anywhere before. I'd like to know how the expression is formed and what physics it signifies. Thank you.

Comment: Are you referring to just the $\delta x$-like expressions?  Or the partial in the numerator with the $\delta x$-like expressions in the denominator?

Comment: I was referring to the second term in each of the flow expressions. The term after the minus sign.

Answer (score 2):

$\rho u$ is the value at the center of the control volume.  But, you need the value of $\rho u$ at the faces of the control volume where fluid enters and leaves.  So you expand in a (truncated) Taylor series to get the values at the entering and leaving faces.  The second term you are referring to is the second term in the Taylor series.

Comment: Aah..so the peculiar form is actually a second term of a Taylor series expansion. That clears up so much, thank you.

Comment: Follow up: What exactly does the negative sign as a consequence of the Taylor series signify? I have an idea but want to be sure.

Comment: The negative sign is to get the value at $x-\delta x/2$ and the positive sign is to get the value at $x+\delta x/2$

Answer (score 1):

The first term is the amount of mass flow, if velocity/density was constant with x,y,z. The second term corrects the first term, by assuming that the product of the density and velocity varies over x,y,z. In other words, the second term merely shows the excess mass that flows out, if d(pv)/dx was non zero and adds it to the mass that would've flown out if pv was constant

Comment: NOTE: that this excess mass might be negative as well.

Comment: So by excess mass you're referring essentially to the mass that enters and exits the fluid element? Sorry, I couldn't quite catch your last statement. English isn't my first language.

Comment: Suppose pv was constant, then the first term is enough to show the mass that flows out of each surface. If pv varies in the first order with x, then the 1st 2 terms are needed to show the total mass through that surface. The second term arises as a correction to what would have been, if only pv was constant.